# How to hide a particular column from the datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm building a page where I need to display a `datatable`.
Based on a condition, this table should display either 5 or 6 columns.

This is my code in `.js` file to display the table with 6 columns:

```
if(Display)
{
    myself.set_DataTable(myself._findjcontrol("tTable1"));    
    myself.get_DataTable().dataTable(
    {
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "aoColumns": [
             { "sType": "string" }, //Column1
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column2
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column3
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column4
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column5
             {"sType": "html"} //Column6
        ],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPage": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "binfo": false,
        "bSortClasses": false
    });
}
else
{
    myself.set_DataTable(myself._findjcontrol("tTable_2"));
    myself.get_DataTable().dataTable(
    {
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "aoColumns": [
             { "sType": "string" }, //Column1
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column2
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column3
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column4
             {"sType": "string" } //Column5
        ],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPage": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "binfo": false,
        "bSortClasses": false
    });
}
```

Based on a condition, I'm repeating the code twice. Is there a way to defined  some kind of property for the column, so, based on condition, I change that property and append it to a column definition. Something like this:

```
var isDisplay = false;
if(Display)
{
   isDisplay = true;
}
else
{
  isDisplay = false;
}

  /* the rest of code */

     {"sType": "string", isDisplay } //Column5

/* the rest of code */
```

Is that possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you need, you can separate your settings with variables without repeating code:

```
var control = "tTable_2"
  , columns = [
             { "sType": "string" }, //Column1
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column2
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column3
             {"sType": "string" }, //Column4
             {"sType": "string" } //Column5
          ];
if(Display)
{
   columns.push({"sType": "html"}); //Column6
   control = "tTable_1";
}


myself.set_DataTable(myself._findjcontrol(control));
myself.get_DataTable().dataTable(
{
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    "aoColumns": columns,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPage": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "binfo": false,
    "bSortClasses": false
});
```

Also, it seems there's a [feature](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) in DataTable that could help you. Try to use the property `bVisible` in the column you want to hide/show:

```
myself.set_DataTable(myself._findjcontrol("tTable1"));    
myself.get_DataTable().dataTable(
{
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    "aoColumns": [
         { "sType": "string" }, //Column1
         {"sType": "string" }, //Column2
         {"sType": "string" }, //Column3
         {"sType": "string" }, //Column4
         {"sType": "string" }, //Column5
         {"sType": "html", "bVisible": Display} //Column6
    ],
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPage": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "binfo": false,
    "bSortClasses": false
});
```

Hope it helps.